# Issues with getting started with webpack 4

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I am following the tutorial exactly as given [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) . But I am amazed that the docs seems outdated. e.g

`npx webpack src/index.js dist/bundle.js` fails with:

> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. Please install
>   'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
>   -> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
>   -> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D

If I install webpack-cli and try again I see this error:

> Hash: af9bc06fd641eb0ffd1e Version: webpack 4.0.0 Time: 3865ms Built
>   at: 2018-2-26 05:10:45  1 asset Entrypoint main = main.js    [1](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)
>   (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]    [2](https://gist.github.com/gricard/e8057f7de1029f9036a990af95c62ba8)
>   (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]    [3]
>   ./src/index.js 212 bytes {0} [built]    [4] multi ./src/index.js
>   dist/bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
>       + 1 hidden module
>
> WARNING in configuration The 'mode' option has not been set. Set
>   'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for
>   this environment.
>
> ERROR in multi ./src/index.js dist/bundle.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'dist/bundle.js' in '/var/app/webpack_demo'  @ multi
>   ./src/index.js dist/bundle.js

I hope I am not doing something crazy, given the popularity of webpack the documentation should reflect the actual behavior. Let me know if I am 
doing something wrong.

## Edit

A details description of upgrade to [webpack 4](https://gist.github.com/gricard/e8057f7de1029f9036a990af95c62ba8),that might be helpful

Comment: Looks like the documentation is still stuck at webpack 3

Comment: Do some research and maybe try compacting your question.  The warning, for instance, is not causing your problem.  https://www.codementor.io/valentino/webpack-4-tutorial-all-you-need-to-know-from-0-conf-to-production-mode-g4lpnr47v

Comment: @DaveKaye , your comments does not make any sense, the docs should reflect the latest changes to the webpack otherwise those are misleading and waste of time , specially for beginner. Even they does not mention which version the docs are addressing.

Comment: @sakhunzi let me try again: Are you asking how to fix the error or commenting on the fact that the documentation isn't up-to-date (which isn't a question)?  With a little research -- can't always trust what a tutorial tells you -- it's not hard to find up-to-date documentation: https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: You can also check this [webpack-4-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project. Hope it helps!

Comment: a related discussion https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16615275

Comment: There is still no mode in configuration page, and it's 4.5.0 now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set mode to development or production in the config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242756/how-to-set-mode-to-development-or-production-in-the-config-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>The Webpack team is working on updating the package docs asap.</s>
New guides and docs are available in the [webpack.js.org](https://webpack.js.org) official site.

<s>In the meantime,</s> You can also read related posts on medium:

- [webpack 4: mode and optimization](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a)
- [webpack 4: released today!!](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-released-today-6cdb994702d4)

Check on GitHub this [Webpack-Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project intended to be a **Webpack 4 tutorial**.
Previous and others links to helpful resources used in the webpack configs are included in the project's `Readme`.
It has two zero-config builds (using the new webpack `mode` option which includes a sets of defaults), and another two using custom configs.

---

Since [webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4), the CLI has been move to `webpack-cli` therefore you need to install also this package in your `devDependencies`.
Also, [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) expect the new `mode` configuration to be set either on the CLI run or the config object.

CLI usage in your `npm` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Set `mode` property in your webpack config object:

```
{
    mode: 'production' // | 'development' | 'none'
}
```

If mode value isn't specified, webpack uses the `production` value (defaulted option). But warns you in the output with:

> WARNING in configuration
>
> The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.

Webpack `mode` reduce the required configuration for an useful build by using a set of defaults (default values for configuration properties  depending the `mode` value):

- `production` enables all kind of optimizations to generate optimized bundles
- `development` enables useful error messages and is optimized for speed
- `none` is a hidden mode which disables everything

Read more on [release notes & changelog](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

Answer (score 49):

You can pass `mode` param in the webpack config or cli command.

Config: `mode: 'development'` or `mode: 'production'`

CLI: `webpack --mode development` or `webpack --mode production`

Answer (score 8):

Got the same issue and after a bit of research found its a problem to be fixed as you can see on this [Github thread](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1295)

**One of the options:**

Inside [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) set `scripts` to either `development` or `production` mode

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

And now when you run `npm run dev` it will give you `bundle.js` but **not minified**.

But when you run `npm run build` it will give you a **minified bundle**

Answer (score 5):

It will be updated very soon, see [this](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-released-today-6cdb994702d4) link for information

> We are very close to having out Migration Guide and v4 Docs Additions complete! To track the progress, or give a helping hand, please stop by our documentation repository, checkout the next branch, and help out!

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 4 docs are not ready yet. I recently migrated from webpack 3 to 4 and it took me quite some time to figure out all the issues.

Here'a my sample repo you can use as reference for migrating from webpack 3 to 4.

https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate

There's one commit specific for migration. Take a look at that for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack config file:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
module.exports = {
  ***
  mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development'
  ***
};
```

In package.json:

```
***
"scripts": {
   "dev": "node ./app.js",
   "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run dev",
   ***
},
***
"dependencies": {
   "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
   ***
}
***
```