# Webpack: After installing webpack and webpack-cli still getting error when running webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have the latest versions of webpack installed:

```
"webpack": "^4.0.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
```

Yet when I run `webpack` in the terminal I get the following:

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with getting started with webpack 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981833/issues-with-getting-started-with-webpack-4)

Comment: More related [tag:webpack-4] documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49178441/7248949)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Seems that you had installed globally only `webpack` and not `webpack-cli`.

Therefore, `npm install -g webpack-cli` solves the issue.

---

#### Explanation and alternative solutions:

Why there is the problem in the first place? The following indicates that both `webpack` and `webpack-cli` packages are locally installed:

> I have the latest versions of webpack installed:
>
> ```
>    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
>    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
> ```

Running `webpack` in your terminal cannot find your locally installed version (provided by `webpack-cli` since [webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4)).
That's because your locals executables folder aren't included in your shell `PATH` variable (list of directories in which the shell looks for commands). The path where `npm` install executables locally is `./node_modules/.bin` (more info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#executables)).

Therefore, instead of try running just `webpack` you need to run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Also, adding to your `package.json` a script which use just `webpack` works because `npm` adds local `./node_modules/.bin/` directory to the shell path before it executes scripts (see [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)).

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
}
```

Then, execute in your terminal: `npm run build`

In recap, I think the `package.json` script is the more clear and desirable way to go.

Comment: Also check on GitHub this [Webpack 4 Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

Try This command Using Npm :

```
npm i -g webpack-cli -D --save
```

Comment: This fixed it but now im getting a different error. I will create a new post for that error.

Comment: for all curious minds, the above command install the "webpack-cli" globally instead of in your local path.
i --> install; g --> global; D -->--save-dev

Comment: this could be a solution, but it is short and without explanations, the answer given by carloluis is by far more complete, and should be the answer for the question

Answer (score 3):

In webpack version ^4.0.0 the webpack CLI was moved into a different package. Although this change has not been reflected in the docs, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/1874) addressing that.

[Carloluis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49186071/8658018) solve your problem, but I'd like to add that its recommended not to do global installs. So a simple `npm install -D webpack-cli` in your project folder will do.

Answer (score 1):

webpack team is moving things in to webpack-cli.  I tried installing webpack-cli globally it gave me GIT error as shown below.

**Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.**

So i first installed GIT from https://gitforwindows.org/ and then installed  webpack-cli using npm.

This blog has detail screenshot and remedy to resolve this error [Angular webpack GIT and webpack-cli error](http://stepbystepschools.net/?p=2312).

Answer (score 0):

I got the error saying I needed to have installed webpack-cli even when I had that already but not webpack.  So I did `yarn add -D webpack`, no need to install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when working on a Rails 6 application

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

If you're using npm, run:

```
npm i -D webpack-cli
```

If you're using yarn, run:

```
yarn add -D webpack-cli
```

**Note**: You do not need to add/define `webpack-cli` in your `package.json` file, since the command to install it also adds `webpack-cli` to your `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file.

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same error. then I figured out by cloning the #webpack from git repo (https://github.com/webpack/webpack ) after that #installed the webpack-cli(
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli --save-dev) using #gitbash.

last check version (webpack -v) if you get the version it is installed successfully.

Hope this will help someone like me. Thank you